# Change DWORD color alpha channel value

Tags: c++, winapi, dword

I have a starting color: 0xffff00ff, which is a:255, r:255, g:0, b:255.

The goal is to change the alpha channel of the color to be less opaque based on a percentage. i.e. 50% opacity for that color is roughly 0x80ff00ff.

How I've tried to reach the solution:

```
DWORD cx = 0xffff00ff;
DWORD cn = .5;

DWORD nc = cx*cn;
```

Comment: Have you studied any bitwise operations?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure/don't know what I would use as the other operand(?). i.e. 0xffff00ff | 0xee or what. nothing gives the desired result.

Comment: Extract the R G and B values by using bitwise operations. Perform the adjustments based on the ints that you get from the first step. Then pack them back into the original byte structure. For example to extract the bits for `a` you want to do use a bitwise `and` operation `cx & ff000000`. Then to get this as an int you have to shift to the right 6 bytes.

Comment: Well, you can divide the problem into smaller problems. One of those is getting the most significant byte. The next is multiplying that byte by the percentage. Finally, setting the most significant byte. Getting and setting the most significant byte are common operations.

Comment: My intution is that you should treat each channel separately. There must be a weighting rule so that when alpha is less than 1.0 (or 255), a color component will be reinforced when another one is weakened, so as to keep the same overall intensity.

Comment: There's'a distance between the source and target colors, that distance may be more easily expressible in HSV terms. Perhaps you could find out what is that distance in HSV with full alpha (1.0), then find what is the color at that same distance with the actual alpha.

Comment: @chris

i have this so far:

    var r = 255;
    var g = 0;
    var b = 255;


    var col = r << 16;
    col += g << 8;
    col += b;

this outputs ff00ff as expected, but when I try to add the alpha channel by doing `col += 255 << 24` it becomes `-ff01`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try unsigned arithmetic. that's good for bitlevel stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I chose to go with:

```
DWORD changeOpacity(DWORD color, float opacity) {
    int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xff;
    int r = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
    int b = color & 0xff;

    int newAlpha = ceil(alpha * opacity);

    UINT newColor = r << 16;
    newColor += g << 8;
    newColor += b;
    newColor += (newAlpha << 24);


    return (DWORD)newColor;
}
```

Comment: slightly better to make newAlpha,r,g,b `DWORD`s. Then there are no issues with signed shifting or too-big shifts in the second part.

Answer (score 4):

```
DWORD cx = 0xffff00ff;
float cn = .5;
DWORD alphaMask=0xff000000;
DWORD nc = (cx|alphaMask)&((DWORD)(alphaMask*cn)|(~alphaMask));
```

This should do the trick. all I'm doing here is setting the first 8 bits of the DWORD to 1's with the or (symbolized by '|') and then anding those bits with the correct value you want them to be which is the alpha mask times cn.  Of course I casted the result of the multiplication to make it a DWORD again.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef union ARGB
{
    std::uint32_t Colour;
    std::uint8_t A, R, G, B;
};


int main()
{
    DWORD cx = 0xffff00ff;
    reinterpret_cast<ARGB*>(&cx)->A = reinterpret_cast<ARGB*>(&cx)->A / 2;

    std::cout<<std::hex<<cx;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tested code (in linux). However, you might find a simpler answer. Note: this is RGBA, not ARGB as you have referenced in your question.

```
double transparency = 0.500;

unsigned char *current_image_data_iterator = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>( const_cast<char *>( this->data.getCString() ) );
unsigned char *new_image_data_iterator = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>( const_cast<char *>( new_image_data->data.getCString() ) );

size_t x;

//cout << "transparency: " << transparency << endl;

for( x = 0; x < data_length; x += 4 ){

    //rgb data is the same
    *(new_image_data_iterator + x) = *(current_image_data_iterator + x);
    *(new_image_data_iterator + x + 1) = *(current_image_data_iterator + x + 1);
    *(new_image_data_iterator + x + 2) = *(current_image_data_iterator + x + 2);

    //multiply the current opacity by the applied transparency
    *(new_image_data_iterator + x + 3) = uint8_t( double(*(current_image_data_iterator + x + 3)) * ( transparency / 255.0 ) );

    //cout << "Current Alpha: " << dec << static_cast<int>( *(current_image_data_iterator + x + 3) ) << endl;
    //cout << "New Alpha: " << double(*(current_image_data_iterator + x + 3)) * ( transparency / 255.0 ) << endl;
    //cout << "----" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as: I wish to change a given rgba color component by a certain factor while keeping the same overall transparency.

For a color with full alpha (1.0 or 255), this is trivial: simply multiply the component without touching the others:

```
//typedef unsigned char uint8
enum COMPONENT {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    ALPHA
};

struct rgba {
    uint8 components[4];
    // uint8 alpha, blue, green, red; // little endian
    uint8 &operator[](int index){
        return components[index];
    }
};

rgba color;
if (color[ALPHA] == 255)
   color[RED] *= factor;
else
    ComponentFactor(color, RED, factor);
```

There's'probably not a single answer to that question in the general case. Consider that colors may be encoded alternatively in [HSL or HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). You might want to keep some of these parameters fixed, and allow other to change.

My approach to this problem would be to first try to find the hue distance between the source and target colors at full alpha, and then convert the real source color to HSV, apply the change in hue, then convert back to RGBA. Obviously, that second step is not necessary if the alpha is actually 1.0.

In pseudo code:

```
rgba ComponentFactor(rgba color, int component, double factor){
    rgba fsrc = color, ftgt;
    fsrc.alpha = 1.0; // set full alpha
    ftgt = fsrc;
    ftgt[component] *= factor; // apply factor
    hsv hsrc = fsrc, htgt = ftgt; // convert to hsv color space
    int distance = htgt.hue - hsrc.hue; // find the hue difference
    hsv tmp = color; // convert actual color to hsv
    tmp.hue += distance; // apply change in hue
    rgba res = tmp; // convert back to RGBA space 
    return res;
}
```

Note how the above rely on type `rgba` and `hsv` to have implicit conversion constructors. Algorithms for conversion may be easily found with a web search. It should be also easy to derive struct definitions for hsv from the rgba one, or include individual component access as field members (rather than using the `[]` operator).
For instance:

```
//typedef DWORD uint32;

struct rgba {

    union {
        uint8 components[4];
        struct {
            uint8 alpha,blue,green,red; // little endian plaform
        }
        uint32 raw;
    };

    uint8 &operator[](int index){
        return components[4 - index];
    }
    rgba (uint32 raw_):raw(raw_){}
    rgba (uint8 r, uint8 g, uint8 b, uint8 a):
        red(r), green(g), blue(b),alpha(a){}
};
```

Perhaps you will have to find a hue factor rather than a distance, or tweak other HSV components to achieve the desired result.